# How are blocks validated in a private blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, synchronization

I am running a private blockchain with 4 nodes, and when i'm creating my Dapp, i have specified for the web3 address only one node ( IP:port, RPC)

So, my questions are:

- How are the others nodes participating in validating the block?
- How they can make their own candidate block?

Comment: Is your private network configured with proof of authority or proof of work?

Comment: @Ismael, yes of course

Answer (score 0):

if you have created private blockchain with POA consensus you have to vote account of other node to be validator. 
You can do by:

```
clique.propose("0x...", true)
```

this has to be done from each validating node. if 50%+1 consensus is reached that account will be validating account and take part in validation process.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never run a blockchain with an even number of miner nodes. Using 4 nodes increases the risk of network split - the most common problem with small private blockchains. So, always use an uneven number like 3, 5 or 7 miner nodes.

I assume your private chain uses PoA and not PoW. Depending on the used underlying algorithm (AuRa, Clique, etc.) of your PoA network there will be more or less a round robin procedure or at least an even distributed load.

You may read here http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2058/paper-06.pdf a brief introduction.